# Binding an Angular Material Selection List

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a Toolbar with a selection list (checkboxes with each list item) using Angular Material 2. I just cannot figure out how to set the checkboxes before the list is displayed and then get the selected items following user interaction.

I am trying the control within a Form thinking I may need this to bind to ngModel, but this doesn't seem to help. My html so far is:

```xml
<form
  novalidate
  #areaSelectForm="ngForm">

<div>
    <mat-selection-list 
                        #areasList="ngModel"
                        [(ngModel)]="model"
                        id="areaListControl"
                        name="areaListControl"
                        (ngModelChange)="onAreaListControlChanged($event)">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas" (click)="onCheckboxClick($event)" [value]="tta">
            {{tta}}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
</div>

</form>
```

This must be a well trodden path but the documentation is difficult to interpret and I cannot seem to find any suitable examples.

Any guidance very welcome please.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

As of version [5.0.0](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/5.0.0), angular material now supports `ngModel` for selection list.

So the code can be simplified to

```xml
<mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas" [value]="tta.name">
        {{tta.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

The release also exposes an `ngModelChange` event for selection list. Here is the updated [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0?file=app/app.component.html)

---

*(Original answer before Angular 5.0.0)*

It appears mat-selection-list does not currently support ngModel (https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/7456), but it looks like it will be supported in the near future. In the meantime you can use a reference variable `#list` to grab the selected options.

```
// component.html
```

```xml
<mat-selection-list #list>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas" [selected]="tta.selected" 
        (click)="onAreaListControlChanged(list)" [value]="tta.name">
        {{tta.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Then pass in the reference variable to your `onAreaListControlChanged(list)` method so you can parse out the selected options.

```
// component.ts
```

```typescript
onAreaListControlChanged(list){
    this.selectedOptions = list.selectedOptions.selected.map(item => item.value);
}
```

To select the checkboxes on load, you can use the `[selected]` property of each `<mat-list-option>`.

```xml
<mat-list-option ... [selected]="tta.selected" ...>
```

To do this you'll need to add another property to your array.

```
// component.ts
```

```typescript
taskTypeAreas: {
    name: string;
    selected: boolean;
}[] = [
    {
        name: 'Area 1',
        selected: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Area 2',
        selected: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Area 3',
        selected: true
    },
];
```

This will make `Area 3` be selected on load. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-material-jyycr7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) demoing this.

---

Comment: Tkx. I could not get the value of the initial list when an item was selected... I did not know I needed to bind the value by myself `[value]="tta.name"` to the `mat-list-option`s

Comment: @LLai Thank you! but can you maybe show in your stackblitz how i can use the selected options to trigger functions or change variables?

Comment: @Budi in the updated answer, you can use the `ngModelChange` event to run some logic when the selected options change.That event is ran whenever an option is selected/deselected

Comment: @Budi I've added a comment to this [file](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-wlnjd9?file=app/app.component.ts). This is where you can call additional methods when the options change

Comment: @LLai Thanks but this was one of the only things that i know before :P I just dont know how i can add here if statements. i tryed with: `if (event.name === "Area 1") {console.log('Place here a function')}` but he dont fire this console.log when i select Area 1...

Comment: @Budi event is an array. You could loop through it and put your conditional in there

Comment: @LLai So `if (event.indexOf('Background Image') >= 0)` is the correct angular way? This looks to me dirty...

Comment: How do we handle reference variable while loop over <mat-selection-list> ?

Comment: I did the same for x lists with y items. The principal is exactly the same, but the model can be bound to selectedOptions[xList] and the selectedOptions is of type {} instead of []. This way, each list gets an entry in the object with as key the name of the list and as value an array with the selected values in that list.

Comment: Can anyone please explain here...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
What are the methods that I can call on event to fetch the value and state of the checkbox?

Answer (score 20):

@LLai's answer is correct, but **you might have noticed that Angular material selection does not work when we use object as a `mat-select-option` `[value]`**

To fix this, Angular material provides `[compareWith]` input.

> @Input()
>   compareWith: (o1: any, o2: any) => boolean
>
> Function used for comparing an option against the selected value when
>   determining which options should appear as selected. The first
>   argument is the value of an options. The second one is a value from
>   the selected value. A boolean must be returned.

For example,

**list-selection.component.ts**

```
export class ListSelectionExample {

  selectedOptions = [{name: 'Boots', id:1}];
  compareFunction = (o1: any, o2: any)=> o1.id===o2.id;

  typesOfShoes: {name: string, id: number }[] = [
    {name: 'Boots', id: 1}, 
    {name: 'Clogs', id: 2},
    {name: 'Loafers', id: 3 },
    {name: 'Moccasins', id: 4},
    {name: 'Sneakers', id:5}
  ];
}
```

**list-selection.component.html**

```
<mat-selection-list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" [compareWith]="compareFunction">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [value]="shoe">
    {{shoe.name}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<p>
  Options selected: {{selectedOptions | json}}
</p>
```

Find here the [live Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hijyk2?file=src/app/list-selection-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for much for point out the compareWith thing. I've been all over looking for solutions and either no one wants a default selection or they aren't using complex objects

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `selectionChange` event emitter to trigger a controller function.

```
<mat-selection-list 
   id="areaListControl"
   name="areaListControl"
   (selectionChange)="onChange($event)"
>
    <mat-list-option 
       *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas" 
       [selected]="tta.selected"
       [value]="tta"
    >
        {{tta}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

And in the controller:

```
onChange(change: MatSelectionListChange) {
   console.log(change.option.value, change.option.selected);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use ViewChildren to access the matListOption instances and then loop through them to check what you need to. Note that the instances won't be available until after the view has loaded you won't be able to do this in onInit.