# Angular mat-selection-list, How to make single checkbox select similar to radio button?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to make single checkbox select from `mat-selection-list`. Similar to radio button which accepts one value from group of values.

Answer (score 52):

**Components >= 9.1.0**

Selection list now supports a single selection mode directly. Enable it with the multiple input set to false.

```
<mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">...
```

**Components < 9.1.0**

You have to set SelectionModel for selectedOptions property of component reference on init.

```
@ViewChild(MatSelectionList, {static: true})
private selectionList: MatSelectionList;

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectionList.selectedOptions = new SelectionModel<MatListOption>(false);
}
```

[MatSelectionList api](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList)

This way you can define initially selected values too.

```
export declare class SelectionModel<T> {
    constructor(_multiple?: boolean, initiallySelectedValues?: T[], _emitChanges?: boolean);
}
```

[GitHub api](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/db879d51111983817cc9e977748408d196f4545f/tools/public_api_guard/cdk/collections.d.ts#L31)

Comment: Sorry for the question. I am new to angular. How do you reference the selection list in the component? How do you get this.selectionList?

Comment: Look at ViewChild decorator: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild. With that you can reference any component or element in template.

Comment: how to change order of the checkbox column as first before details?

Comment: I can't use the same way in @ViewChildren with QueryList. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @SasinduLakshitha You don't have to use '@ViewChildren' since 9.1.0 version. See edited answer.

Answer (score 19):

What you'd need to do is:

- Listen for `selectionChange`
- Clear all with `deselectAll()` method
- Set it as selected again

I modified the original example from the API page, added a ViewChild for the selection list and subscribe to the `selectionChange` event.

```
ngOnInit(){

    this.shoes.selectionChange.subscribe((s: MatSelectionListChange) => {          

        this.shoes.deselectAll();
        s.option.selected = true;
    });

    // WARNING: Don't attempt to do the following to select the value
    // it won't trigger the value change event so it will remain unchecked
    // this.shoes.selectedOptions.select(s.option);

    // If interested source is here : 
    // https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/fa4ddd0a13461b2f846e114fd09f8f4e21b814b1/src/lib/list/selection-list.ts
}
```

Working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3pfu2-6n5cnt

See also: 
https://material.angular.io/components/list/api

Comment: Note: I reported the issue with selectionModel.select not working and it has already has a push fixed - so in future this should work

Comment: Good solution if you need the checkboxes because multiple= flase hides them.

Answer (score 9):

To begin with, `mat-selection-list` is not suitable for a single-value selection, as it veers away from [its intent](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CheckBox):

> Checkboxes in a group are non-exclusive options; more than one checkbox in a group can be checked at any given time

What you're looking for is the radio-button element itself, because semantically [it stands for](https://www.w3.org/wiki/RadioButton):

> A radio button is one of a group of controls representing mutually-exclusive choices

Unfortunately Angular Material does not include a `mat-radio-list` component. But you can still achieve it by including a `mat-radio-button` inside you `mat-list-item`. This will provide best practice, as it denotes to the user that the list in view is intended for *mutually-exclusive choices* (unlike checkboxes that denote multiple-choice). And since the radio buttons are updating a single variable, you get exclusivity:

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let x of [0,1,2]; let i = index">
    <mat-radio-button [value]="i" (change)="selection = $event.value">
        Item {{x}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

[Check a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-with-radios?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.html)

Comment: I agree that you should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes if it's single-selection -- that's the point of radio styling, after all -- but it's kind of a coincidence that `mat-radio-button` works inside of `mat-list-item`, and can break down if you use more advanced features. For example, try adding a `matListIcon` to your list -- now the radio button is constrained inside a "line container" and goes crazy as soon as you click it. We need a `mat-radio-list`, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the multiple option of MatSelectionList to false:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.links.selectedOptions._multiple = false;
}
```

and you're done. Also by doing this you will be able to deselect the selected checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

Bit late to the party, but here's a solution I came up with using a directive to extend the `mat-selection-list` behaviour.

```
import { SelectionModel } from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { Directive, Host, Input, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { MatListOption, MatSelectionList } from "@angular/material/list";

@Directive({
    selector: "mat-selection-list[multiple]"
})
export class MatSelectionListMultipleDirective implements OnChanges {
    private matSelectionList: MatSelectionList;

    @Input()
    public multiple: boolean;

    constructor(@Host() matSelectionList: MatSelectionList) {
        this.matSelectionList = matSelectionList;
    }

    public ngOnChanges(): void {
        if (this.multiple) {
            this.matSelectionList.selectedOptions = new SelectionModel<MatListOption>(true, this.matSelectionList.selectedOptions.selected);
        }
        else {
            let selected = this.matSelectionList.selectedOptions.selected.splice(0, 1);
            this.matSelectionList.selectedOptions = new SelectionModel<MatListOption>(false, selected);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this...

```
<mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
...
</mat-selection-list>
```

Ideally we would have a radio control instead of the checkbox, but I think this workaround is OK until the angular material team support this officially.

Comment: there is no input like multiple in mat-selection-list.

Comment: Not currently - this directive adds that input and behavior.

Comment: If you can not upgrade to the newest Angular Material, and perhaps want to use *ngIf on your mat-selection-list this is the cleanest solution!

Answer (score 3):

In order to make single checkbox select from mat-selection-list if you are not using Angular Material v6+ here is the workaround i used :
Let's say we have a list of categories checkboxes.

In your HTML :

```
    <mat-selection-list>
        <mat-list-option  (selectionChange)="handleSelection($event, category)" *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">
            <span >{{category.name}}</span>
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

In your .TS :

```
  handleSelection(event, categorySelected) {
      if (event.selected) {
          event.source.selectionList.options.toArray().forEach(element => {
              if (element.value.name!= categorySelected.name) {
                 element.selected = false;
              }
         });
      }
  }
```

The key here is to use the property selectionChange on the MatListOption and not MatSelectionList.

Comment: Tried a half dozen solutions. This is the only solution that worked for me.  My `mat-selection-list` is displayed in a modal that uses `ngIf` to show/hide, so registering list as a `@ViewComponent` does nothing. The mat-angular team should have made this a simple attribute.

Answer (score 2):

From a philosophical and UX perspective, you need to use radio buttons. This is the only way to provide user-friendly "as expected" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ngFor for each mat-checkbox, you can do something similar to following in HTML template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let address of person.addresses; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="personCheckedIndex === i" (change)="customerCheckboxChange($event, i)"></mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```

and in TS:

```
public personCheckedIndex = -1;

// Called from template when checkbox value changes    
personCheckboxChange(event: MatCheckboxChange, index: number) {
    // This allows only one checkbox to be checked among each checkbox
    this.personCheckedIndex = event.checked ? index : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare the `[selected]` attribute of `mat-list-option`

for example:

```
<mat-selection-list #list>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of myList" 
        [(mgModel)]="selectedOption"
        [selected]="item.id === selectedOption.id" 
        [value]="item">
        {{item.name}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

by this way you reach just one selection without changing any MatSelectionList hidden property.

Also you can do it by replacing `ngModel` with controller logic, 
by this way you will save the last selection object in class variable.

```
<mat-list-option (selectionChange)="onChange($event)"`
```

see also [Binding an Angular Material Selection List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349528/binding-an-angular-material-selection-list)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably a `<mat-radio-group>` rather than a `<mat-selection-list>`, Its a list of options but only one option can be selected. an example can be found at the  [Angular Material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview).

But be advised that instead of a checkbox you'll get a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**ts:**

`import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';`

```
import { MatSelectionList } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
    selector : 'app-xxx',
    templateUrl: './xxx.component.html'
})
export class xxxComponent implements OnInit {
    public data: Object[] = [ {name : "name 1" }, {name : "name 2" }, {name : "name 3" }, {name : "name 4" } ];
    @ViewChild('element_id') names_list: MatSelectionList;
    ngOnInit() {
        // only if the element is visible on the page, otherwise move this block and execute it until the list is displayed
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.names_list.selectedOptions._multiple = false;
        },0);
    }
}
```

**template:**

```
<mat-selection-list #element_id>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let d of data">
        {{ d.name }}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'mat-checkbox' instead of 'mat-selection-list' and play with click event like this:

**HTML**

```
 <div *ngFor=" ... loop">
              <mat-checkbox #checkBoxes (click)="changeCheckBox()">
              </mat-checkbox>
 </div>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChildren('checkBoxes') checkBoxes: QueryList<MatCheckbox>;

 changeCheckBox() {
    this.checkBoxes.filter((checkbox: MatCheckbox) =>
      checkbox.checked === true
    )[0].checked = false;
  }
```

remember that all check boxes default value is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Angular Material 9.1.0, selection list supports a single selection mode. Enable it with the `multiple` input set to `false`: https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList

Comment: Angular 11 [multiple]="false"  not working for me got error: ` error NG8002: Can't bind to 'multiple' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-selection-list'.` any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
I've got it working with a tick, changing css

```css
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-outer-circle{
      border-radius:2px;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-inner-circle{
        border-radius:2px;
        background-color: transparent!important;
        border-bottom: 4px solid white;
        border-right:4px solid white;
        height:30px;  
        width:15px;
        margin-top: -8px;
       margin-left: 3px;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle{
       background:#ff4081!important;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-inner-circle{
       transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
    }
 
    :host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button .mat-radio-ripple{
      height: 20px; /*double of your required circle radius*/
      width: 20px;  /*double of your required circle radius*/
      left: calc(50% - 10px); /*'10px'-same as your required circle radius*/
      top: calc(50% - 10px); /*'10px'-same as your required circle radius */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy solution though not the perfect one but it will get your job done!

```js
 
change() {
    if (this.formGroup.get('control1').value === true) {
      this.formGroup.get('control2').setValue(false);
    } else if (this.formGroup.get('control2').value === true){
      this.formGroup.get('control1').setValue(false);
    }
 }
```

```html
<mat-checkbox [formControlName]="'control1'" color="primary" (change)="change()">
   control1
</mat-checkbox>

<mat-checkbox color="primary" [formControlName]="'control2'" (change)="change()">
   control2
</mat-checkbox>
```