# Angular Mat List Single Selectable Option

Tags: angular-material

I am aware of [Angular mat-selection-list, How to make single checkbox select similar to radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277904/angular-mat-selection-list-how-to-make-single-checkbox-select-similar-to-radio) and related API, however

```
<mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
```

does not seem to be working well.
Here is minimal reproduction snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r13hpx?file=src/app/list-selection-example.html

And its screenshot:
[Checkboxes are not being rendered properly when multiple att set to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y22Fz.png)

Is this a bug? Did not find it reported anywhere :( ...

Cheers!

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Classes are set correctly on options and the selection value is actually also set correctly. Only the template is conditioning out the checkboxes, so it is not being rendered at all when multiple attribute set to falsy value. Will report on to dev team.

Comment: reported as https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18847